# One divided by zero.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is one(or any other number) divided by zero? I have tried to find this out, but the only answer I could think of is infinity, due to the fact that zero is worth nothing. Nothing can fit into anything infinite times, so this is my logic. I repeat: What is one (or any other number) divided by zero?

Comment: Do you understand my question?

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero). In the standard algebraic structure of $\Bbb R$ the division by zero is not defined.

Comment: It's undefined. It just doesn't really mean anything by itself.

Comment: Division by zero is impossible - division is the inverse operation of multiplication. There is no number that multiplied by zero is one.

Comment: $\frac 10$ is undefined.  For any real number $x \neq 0,\;\; \frac x0$ is undefined.

Comment: We have that $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=\infty$$and$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty$$however, $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined. Division by zero leads to different contradictions in math so many have chosen to simply leave it as undefined. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero), division by zero is "meaningless" and "undefined".

It is often confused to be infinite, because $\frac 1 x \to \infty$ as $x\to 0$ or if we defined division on $a\div b$ as the number of times you subtract $b$ from $a$ to get to $0$. Both of these cases produce infinite results, however division is defined as inverse multiplication, which makes division by zero meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of questions on this site about division by zero.

Here is the answer that I find best.

The *definition* of "$1/x$" is "the number you multiply $x$ by to get $1$ for an answer". Since there is no such number when $x=0$, the expression $1/0$ is meaningless.

This definition works nicely when you get to modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

$$1 \div 0$$

It is undefined.

So we define division based on multiplication. We define

$$a = b \div c$$

If we could find a unique value $a$, such that 
$$a \times c =b$$

And you'll find in the case of $1\div 0$, there is no such value exists, because every value multiply by $0$ is $0$, but can never be $1$.